# Calling a flow using Groovy Script in Mule 4

Tags: mule

I need to make a call to a flow using groovy script in mule 4. Can someone let me know if they have tried it using Mule 4

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but I would HIGHLY recommend that you do NOT do it.

You will have to dig deep down into the Mule Java APIs and couple yourself to them and also add a lot of your own error handling etc. and be wary of platform updates and the if the Java API changes.

Personally I would restructure you app to only have 'business logic' in scripts and let Mule do the flow lookups elsewhere.

You can even lookup flows in dataweave.

But here is a rough working example(Note you will have to harden this code yourself):

```
<flow name="test-flow">
        <scheduler>
            <scheduling-strategy>
                <fixed-frequency frequency="100000"></fixed-frequency>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-payload value="bla bla" />
        <scripting:execute engine="groovy" doc:name="Toggle flow" doc:id="2eb6f071-bdef-4d3d-926d-2565fcd62d33">
            <scripting:code>
                import org.mule.runtime.api.message.Message;
                import org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.CoreEvent;
                import org.mule.runtime.core.api.event.EventContextFactory;
                flow=registry.lookupByName(&quot;another-flow&quot;).get();
                thisflow=registry.lookupByName(&quot;test-flow&quot;).get();
                msg = Message.builder().value(payload).build();
                event =CoreEvent.builder(EventContextFactory.create(thisflow,
                org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.component.config.DefaultComponentLocation.fromSingleComponent("add-location"))).message(msg).build();
                result =flow.process(event);
            </scripting:code>
        </scripting:execute>
    </flow>

    <flow name="another-flow">
        <logger level="ERROR" message="Another Flow #[payload]" />
    </flow>
```

You need to fetch the current flow and the flow you want to call.

Using the Mule APIs - construct a Mule Event, Messgae, payload etc. You will also need to add any attributes you need etc.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your response. I was able to achieve the functionality by using Java class instead of groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to call mule "static flow" like When I use the above groovy script and it will call the flow ( its starting the called flow and get the values) and get the values.

### Requirement :

Like, Mule Flow A is running independently.

Mule flow B wants to access the Flow A variable with out starting the flow A using groovy or python Script.

Note: Can do with flow reference and lookup but would like to implement using script.